# Horizontal scrolling works only from the first slide

Tags: jquery, horizontal-scrolling

I've made this:

**HTML**

```
<a id="1" href="#">Slide 1</a>
<a id="2" href="#">Slide 2</a>
<a id="3" href="#">Slide 3</a>

<div class="scroller">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="slide-1">
            <h1>First slide</h1>
            <p>content</p>
        </div>
        <div id="slide-2">Second</div>
        <div id="slide-3">Third</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.scroller {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
.container {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500%;
}
.container div {
    height: 400px;
    width: 100vw;
    float: left;
}

#slide-1 {
    background: red;
}

#slide-2 {
    background: violet;
}

#slide-3 {
    background: grey;
}
```

**JS**

```
$("a").on("click", function() {
    var e = $(this).attr("id");
    var t = $("#slide-" + e).position().left;
    $(".scroller").animate({
        scrollLeft: t
    }, 600)
})
```

And demo is here: jsfiddle.net/dxcmnpog/2/

When a user clicks on the anchor tag (a#slide-x), the script should slide left to the actual div#slide-x.

The problem is that it only works when the visible slide is the first one. So when a user is on the 2nd slide and wants to go on the 3rd slide, it doesn't work.

Do you have any idea what causes that? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("a").on("click", function() {
    var e = $(this).attr("id");
    var t = $("#slide-" + e).width()*(e-1);
    console.log(t);
    $(".scroller").animate({
        scrollLeft: t
    }, 600)
})
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/dxcmnpog/9/

I've used width() of elements, and scrolling is related to it. So, when first element is visible (slide1/link1 -> position/scrolling is 0, for second one, scrolling Left is: width*1, third one: width*2, etc, etc...

P.S. Add console.log(t) to your fiddle and you will see problem which causing more bugs.